# RelayCommand<bool> throws invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I'm trying to parameterize a RelayCommand but am getting a runtime cast exception.

Here are the relevant xaml and view model lines:

**XAML**

```
<MenuItem Header="Save Project As" Command="{Binding Main.SaveProjectAsRelayCommand}" CommandParameter="false" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
public RelayCommand<bool> SaveProjectAsRelayCommand { get; set; }

SaveProjectAsRelayCommand = new RelayCommand<bool>(SaveProjectAs, ProjectTaskCanExecute);

private void SaveProjectAs(bool b){...}
private bool ProjectTaskCanExecute(bool b){...}
```

When I click the File Menu, GalaSoft throws an

> InvalidCastException ("Specified cast is not valid)

When I remove the parameter from everything, works fine.

Do I have to do something to enable "false" to be cast to a bool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Type Converter must be converting it to a string instead of a bool.

```
<MenuItem Header="Save Project As" Command="{Binding Main.SaveProjectAsRelayCommand}" >
 <MenuItem.CommandParameter>
      <x:Boolean>False<x:Boolean>
 </MenuItem.CommandParameter>
</MenuItem>
```

Try the above. You will have to use the following name space in the XAML.

```
xmlns:x="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Adil. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could create a property in your 'main' that you bind to

```
<MenuItem Header="Save Project As" Command="{Binding Main.SaveProjectAsRelayCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Main.IsTask}" />
```

In the main VM you will than have

```
public bool IsTask{get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Since only two UI commands would be affected by this state (bool = "includeExtras"), and both of the handlers in the view model end up calling the same method in the business model (which takes this same parameter), I like having it handled from the start as a call parameter.